# Как получить время с атомных часов спутника

Tags: java, android, gps

Я делаю приложение, которому нужно очень точное время. Посмотрев в интернете я так и не нашел способ получения времени GPS.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить время GPS

Comment: можно к ntp серверу подключится и оттуда брать время например или вам именно с gps нужно тащить время?

Comment: нужно именно с gps

Comment: вот например вопрос по вашей тематике - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038229/gps-time-representation-library, вам по факту нужно искать решение не на андроид а на java а потом его просто адаптировать для своих нужд

Comment: Вот здесь в статье рассматривается вопрос получения точноговременни с gps. Но - не применительно к андроиду. https://habr.com/ru/post/118266/ Может, это чем то поможет?

Comment: Я полагаю, вам нужен метод [GnssClock.getTimeNanos()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssClock#getTimeNanos()). О том, как этим пользоваться, можно спросить гугл. Среди первых ссылок он выдаёт [ответ на Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864287/android-gnss-time-for-synchronization).